# Como resolver un problema de decimales al realizar un calculo de cuotas a pagar en VISUAL BASIC .NET

Tags: vb.net, double

Tengo el siguiente proyecto, realizar un formulario en el cual especifico el monto a cobrar, detallo una cantidad de anticipo que es el 20% del monto a cobrar, el saldo lo divido para 6 meses, pero estoy batallando con los decimanes Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
            'variable que recive el valor de la caja de texto Monto.
            mt = txt_monto.Text
            'variable que recive el valor del 20% del monto ingresado
            tt = (mt * 20) / 100
            'caja de texto Anticipo recibe el valor del 20% del monto ingresado
            txt_anticipo.Text = tt.ToString("N1")

            'variable para identificar la cantidad de meses
            Dim meses As Integer
            'Variable obtiene el valor del numericupdown
            meses = nu_meses.Value
            Dim v1 As Double
            Dim v2 As Double

            'variable para calcular el saldo de la deuda
            v1 = mt - tt
            'variable para identificar el valor de cada cuota
            v2 = v1 / nu_meses.Value
```

El problema que tengo es que por 1 centavo no cuadran los valores, como puedo resolver

Comment: no uses double como tipo de variable, usa decimal...

Comment: Saludos al usar Decimal como tipo de variable, en la caja de texto de anticipo me da 38.5 no se por que lo redondea a ese valor.}

Comment: Podrias ser mas claro? antes dijiste que los decimales no te daban... ahora te dan algo erroneo.. que es lo que queres que te de?

Comment: Revisa [redondeo del banquero](https://www.teknoplof.com/tag/redondeo-bancario/)

Comment: El redondeo lo realizas tu mismo en `txt_anticipo.Text = tt.ToString("N1")`. Si pones `N2` tendrás dos decimales

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puede hacer, lo que hago en si, es recorrer toda la grilla y sumar cada valor, con este dato le restas a la parte q dividiste, así obtendrás la diferencia, y esta diferencia sumarla a la ultima fila. De esta manera te cuadrará la suma de las cuotas con el total que fraccionaste.

Para este ejemplo: El total de la grilla es 153.84, el monto fraccionado fue 153.83 la diferencia es -0.01, esta diferencia se suma a la cuota 6 quedando en 25.63, Así si validas la suma del total de la grilla serian los 153.83 que fraccionaste.

Es una rutina simple pero soluciona este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Es posible que tu respuesta sea apropiada, pero no veo el código que resuelve el problema. Si la misma no lleva código (porque lo dejas a expensas de quién ha preguntado), entonces debería de ir a la zona de comentarios. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].